# wifi keeps shutting down or dropping

Tags: wireless-networking

To access the net I share the internet connection on my phone through mobile hotspot. When the phone screen is locked the connection drops all the time. If I keep the phone screen turned on the wifi won't drop anymore. Is there a fix for this annoying issue?

What I already tried:
1. Change the power adapter settings on the computer and the phone
2. Update network drivers.

On the phone side, the Data Save option is inactive as well as the ultra data save.

Plus I tried to do this with another computer and it works fine when the screen is turned off.

Comment: It really depends on the phone. iOS does not have this problem, at least past iOS 8. Also, the specs of your phone may also be causing it. For example, some phones may turn off their wireless connections when they are on sleep, unless applications that require internet are running in the background. Check the specs and see if your phone is viable to do that.

Comment: Never had this problem in Android either. It must be a problem specific to your phone.

Comment: This happens only with my personal laptop. I have tried to connect to my wireless hotspot with other computers and it has worked for hours without interruptions. My phone is Samsung Galaxy J6.